# Can a catenary be a parabola?

Tags: calculus, conic-sections, curves

In one of my text books (Thomas' Calculus, I think), one of the exercises asked us to find the arc length of a hanging wire that was weighted such that it traced a parabola, or something to that effect. Point is, it wanted us to find the arc length of a parabola, and tried to justify it with a real world example.

Now, I know that, in general, a hanging wire forms a catenary, not a parabola, so my question is: is it possible for a catenary to be a parabola, at least within a given finite width?

Comment: To be fair, it *is* possible to appropriately weight a wire so that its shape makes a parabola. This holds if the weight is uniformly distributed along the $x$-axis (as opposed to along the length of the curve as for a hanging wire). For example a suspension bridge has this property.

Comment: "At least within a given finite width" -- with enough tolerance, any continuous function can approximate any other continuous function, although it might be interesting to find out what the gap between a catenary and a parabola is (in terms of the parameters of the two functions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible. For instance, take a point $P$ of a parabola. Consider the straight line $l_P$ passing through $P$ parallel to the axis of symmetry of the parabola. Let $l_P'$ be the reflection of $l$ on the normal to the parabola at $P$. Then all these straight lines $l_P'$ have a point in common (which is the focus of the parabola). The catenary doesn't have this property.

Comment: Seems to ignore the weighting of the wire.

Comment: What have physical considerations to do with my answer (or with the question)?

Comment: As discussed in the main comments, the wire is assumed to be non-uniform. Your answer accurately responds to the question as explicitly phrased, but it seems clear that Thomas was intending a situation which is perfectly possible.

Comment: @KevinArlin I deliberated on whether to ask this on physics or math. I chose math because I was curious about whether a (mathematical) catenary could be a parabola, and Mr. Santos answered that question. Once the 24 hour grace period is up, I will be accepting this answer, as it answers my question (though that shouldn't discourage others from adding more examples of how catenaries can't be parabolas).

Comment: @KevinArlin Also, thanks to Moo's links, I now know the answer to the physical question as well. I may decide to Q&A that at physics.se myself later.